# show all the products that have same category name in PHP/Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display all the products with the same `category` in a php page.

the products are saved in mysql database!

in my header I have the following code which will show/display the categories from the mysql database in my `header.php`:

```
<?php
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php"; 
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM products";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $category = $row["category"];
             $dynamicList .= '<li class="categories">
        <div>
                    <div id="lookbookmedia" class="column"> <a href="product_list.php?category=' . $category . '">' . $category . '</a></div>
        </div>
      </li><li><a  href="product_list.php?category=' . $category . '">' . $category . '</a></li>';
    }   
} else {
    $dynamicList = "NO Cats Yet!";
}
?>
```

currently I am using the following code in my `product_list.php` page but this will only show one product and that is the `LAST` one in the mysql database no matter which category I click on in my header!

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['category'])) {
// Run a select query to get my letest 6 items
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "config/connect.php"; 
    $category = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['category']);

$dynamicList2 = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category= category LIMIT 25" ;
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($query); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $category = $row["category"];
             $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
             $dynamicList2 = '<table  class="border"  style="float:left; margin-left:43px; text-align:center; background-color:#e3e3e3; margin-bottom:10px;" width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" width="300" height="450" alt="' . $product_name . '" longdesc="' . $product_name . '" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:#000; font-weight:bold;">' . $product_name . '</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:#000; font-weight:bold;">Price: £' . $price . '</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">View Product Details</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
    }
}
} else {
    $dynamicList2 = "We have no products listed in our store yet";
}

?>
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong!

could someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong here:

```
$category = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['category']);

$dynamicList2 = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='".$category."' LIMIT 25" ;
```

Change your literal **category** for the variable `$category`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. with your suggestion that single product disappeared as well! so nothing was displayed on the page!

Comment: Category is stored as a number or a string?

Comment: sorry I should have said this in my question. the category is saved as a column in the `products` table as a string. i.e. the categories of Shoes, Boots get saved as Shoes, Boots in the `category` column in the `products` table.

Comment: I think that your while loop is also wrong as you are overwriting `$dynamicList2`in every iteration. Try `$dynamicList2 .= `